# Which file or directory dose "apt-get update" affect

Tags: apt

I have updated my system and I want to do some tests needed to remove the cache. I know the command download the packages list from the repositories,but where is the local database to store this infomation.

Comment: For removing cache - i think `sudo apt-get clean` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Complete List of files used by `apt-get`** (From `man apt-get`):

```
FILES
       /etc/apt/sources.list
           Locations to fetch packages from. Configuration Item: Dir::Etc::SourceList.

       /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
           File fragments for locations to fetch packages from. Configuration Item: Dir::Etc::SourceParts.

       /etc/apt/apt.conf
           APT configuration file. Configuration Item: Dir::Etc::Main.

       /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/
           APT configuration file fragments. Configuration Item: Dir::Etc::Parts.

       /etc/apt/preferences
           Version preferences file. This is where you would specify "pinning", i.e. a preference to get certain packages from a
           separate source or from a different version of a distribution. Configuration Item: Dir::Etc::Preferences.

       /etc/apt/preferences.d/
           File fragments for the version preferences. Configuration Item: Dir::Etc::PreferencesParts.

       /var/cache/apt/archives/
           Storage area for retrieved package files. Configuration Item: Dir::Cache::Archives.

       /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/
           Storage area for package files in transit. Configuration Item: Dir::Cache::Archives (partial will be implicitly
           appended)

       /var/lib/apt/lists/
           Storage area for state information for each package resource specified in sources.list(5) Configuration Item:
           Dir::State::Lists.

       /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/
           Storage area for state information in transit. Configuration Item: Dir::State::Lists (partial will be implicitly
           appended)
```

In case of `sudo apt-get update`, following may help you:

- `/etc/apt/sources.list`
- `/etc/apt/sources.listd/`
- **`/var/lib/apt/lists/`**
- **`/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/`**

Comment: It's the directory of /var/lib/apt/lists/,this infomation is stored    in /var/lib/apt/list/partial/ when it is trasmitting.I get it, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

From *man apt-get*:

> **clean**
>              clean clears out the local repository of retrieved package files.
>              It removes everything but the lock file from
>              /var/cache/apt/archives/ and /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/.

So, to clear the cache:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Comment: `/var/cache/apt/archives/` is affected by `sudo apt-get install` not with `sudo apt-get update`!?

Comment: @Pandya- Correct.